# Hover on multiple concurrent DIVs

Tags: css, html, hover

I am messing around with some navigation for a site and I want three images floating on the right of the screen (which I have). I then want to be able to hover over one of the images and have a menu pop-up next to that image. I can do this with one, but as soon as I introduce the next image in the vertical sequence, the first one stops working. Why?

My HTML:

```
<DIV id="parent"><a href="#issue49"><img src = "images/parent.png"></a></DIV>
<DIV id="student"><a href="#issue49"><img src = "images/student.png"></a></DIV>
<DIV id="teacher"><a href="#issue49"><img src = "images/staff.jpg"></a></DIV>
```

`<DIV id="pnavi"> <a href="#issue49"><img src = "images/parent.png"></a></DIV>`

My CSS:

```
#parent {
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#student {
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#teacher {
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#parent:hover + #pnavi {
  visibility: visible;
}

#pnavi {
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

If I comment out the student and teacher DIV, hover on parent shows #pnavi. Remove the comment (or even add a break after the DIV) and it all stops.

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jas08/cqqYd/)

I have the second two DIVs currently commented out so that the hover works (first time using Fiddle so I hope I did it right..).

Comment: Can you post this on a fiddle?

Comment: #pnavi is a hidden element to the left of the #parent. The hover over #parent is supposed to change the visibility of #pnavi to visible (see #parent:hover + #pnavi {)

Comment: The elements on each side of the [`+ combinator`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-d-combinators) must be immediate, adjacent siblings. Could you edit the question to show where `#pnavi` is on your markup?

Comment: Ah, thanks bfavaretto! Because my #pnavi DIV tag was defined after my three DIVs above, it wasn't an adjacent sibling. Simply moving where I had the DIV tag in my HTML fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `+` ([direct adjacent combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-d-combinators)), the elements on each side must be adjacent siblings. So, on your case, `#pnavi` must be right after `#parent` on the markup (and, by consequence, on the DOM).

There is also an [indirect adjacent combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-i-combinators), `~`, that only requires the elements to be siblings, but not directly next to each other. So you might use `#parent:hover ~ #pnavi`. I'm not sure about browser support, though. It works in Chrome on my mac. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cqqYd/1/).